# Parameters of getView method - android

Tags: android, parameters

can you tell me how i can find out the right parameters for this method:
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

I have a ListView with a custom adapter. The listview looks like this:

TextView EditText
TextView EditText
TextView EditText...

What is the convertView and parent parameter?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html. check the `getView(params)` in the docs

Comment: There are no more information about this parameter. I already looked it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

1. position is the position of the data displayed by the view in the data set.
2. convertView is used for recycling views so that you don't have a bunch running at once
3. parent is the containing adapter for the view, which for this case would be the ListView I assume.

I hope this helps

Comment: I would like to get the content of the edittext. Do you know what i am doing wrong? This is my try:    [code]                    ListView listview1 = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1));
Adapter adapter = listview1.getAdapter();
View input_item_view = (View)adapter.getView(0,null,listview1);
EditText input_item = (EditText)input_item_view.findViewById(R.id.inputfield);
String input = input_item.getText().toString();                  The  String is empty.[/code]

Comment: I don't think getView is neccesary there. Why not try:
EditText input_item = (EditText)listview1.findViewById(R.id.inputfield);
and then get the text from that

Answer (score 1):

The `getView` method of your custom adapter will get called when list items are to be displayed. You don't need to provide parameters for the method, Android system will provide them. "parent" will be your list view, "convertView" will be null when the first list item is displayed. You can also re-use convertView. A correct way to implement custom adapter is http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Android-UI-Tips-and-Tricks

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with find?

If you `override` `getView()` method inside your adapter class then you will be able to know each line's views content.

That would be something like:

```
@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_id);
  EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText_id);
  // position param is the the correspondent line on the list to this view, you can use this parameter to do anything like:

  if(position==0) {
      textView.setText("This is the first line!");
  }

 // Do anything you want with your views... populate them. This is the place where will be defined the content of each view.
}
```

If you already have your list populated and want to retrieve some value when selecting an view, then implement a listener to your `ListView`, like below.

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_id);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long long) {
          TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_id); 
          EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_id);

          String textViewText = textView.getText();
          String editTextText = editText.getText().toString();

      }                 
});
```

Comment: I need to get access to the components. So i try to call the method. Or how can i get the values of the views?

Comment: @JavaForAndroid, take a look at my edit above. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know that this should work. But i am using onMenuItemSelected. The comment by ramboslice solved my problem. =)

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` is a method that run several times, every time your program inflate a row in your list it will be running.
The parent is your custom adapter that you inflate a row into it.
`convertView` is the GUI(view) of the row in the `Position` position in your adapter.